# CPU Speed checker for Lumia

Tags: lumia

Is there any application available for checking the speed of the CPU for Lumia?

Comment: You can check the CPU model details on the Nokia website, although the only difference from an end user perspective is in the maximum video resolutions.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the store and search for benchmark. There are multiple apps that will give you statistics about nearly every aspect if your phone.